# Illegal Offset Type: Foreach Looping through array

Tags: php, laravel

I've got this loop:

```
@foreach($books as $listing)
  <h4>{{ $books[$listing]['name'] }} - {{ $books[$listing]['author'] }}</h4>
  <p>[[ $books[$listing]['location'] }} - {{ $books[$listing]['condition'] }}.</p>
@endforeach
```

It produces an error:
`Illegal offset type (View: then goes on to point to the .blade.php view path`.

My array's elements can basically be referenced like this: `$books[0]['author']`. I want to be able to loop through the array and change the value of [0] each iteration.

I'm really new to this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting that error is that you are trying to use `$listing` as the key for `$books`. Instead you should be doing something like:

```
@foreach($books as $key => $listing)
    {{{ $listing['name'] }}} or {{{ $books[$key]['name'] }}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `foreach`, you don't have to index your original array anymore. So instead of doing

```
$books[$listing]['name']
```

you can do

```
$listing['name']
```

The `$listing` there is not an index to an element in the array, but an element in the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error, use the original array you are trying to loop like so:

```
 @foreach($books as $key => $listing)

{{{ $books['name'] }}} or {{{ $books['name'] }}}

 @endforeach
```

Comment: why the same value twice?